# 6 YO Honda CB Twister 100 cc bike delivers rough (struggles to keep pulling) power output post 40-50 kmph

Tags: honda, motorcycle, engine-load

It's just that the engine struggles to put out more power, with a lot of roughness in the engine sound post 50 kmph - What might be the problem? The recommended engine oil is 10w30 for this, but i've been running it on a 10w40 and 20w40 of late due to lack of good quality oils in 10w30 grade. Using semi-synthetics so far. Regularly serviced for the past half year.

The period before that, the engine had an oil leakage problem from the oil gauge (oil pouring opening) and it seemed like the engine isn't maintained that well prior to this.

Do you think the piston rings are worn out?

Is this bike bad?

More Info :

1. This is a [2010 Model CB Twister](http://www.indiancarsbikes.in/motorcycles/honda-twister-cb-110-specifications-price-colors-423/) - This is a carburetor model
   with 4 gears.
2. This happens when i seek to hit the higher rev ranges
   of the bike.  When i shift from 2nd to 3rd gear, i can tell that the 3rd gear seems a bit worn out, since it is very rough in the 3rd, but smooth in the fourth until we reach say, the 4th gear's upper range and it gets really rough then.
3. Bike doesn't have a RPM meter so tough to say exact numbers - but safe to say that this roughness gets encountered in the mid-higher rev ranges, especially in the upper range of the final gear (4th) when it does seem like the bike can deliver more, it gets really rough, and contrived, as if the engine has to do a lot of work to put out power.

Comment: Changed Engine cover gasket, air filter, spark plug with genuine parts. Doesn't seem like this machine has an oil filter (no apparent opening)

Comment: Speeds are nice to have regarding knowing when it's occurring.  A very nice add on of data would be "what gear are you in when it happens?"  AND "How many RPM's are you at when it happens?"   How much is the throttle open when this occurs?    This would be very helpful, please edit your question and add in these bits.  As well, what year is your bike?  Do you have the fuel injected model or the carburetor version?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me on this. I've added a little information but not sure if it is all you need.

Comment: Have you made any headway on this issue?

Comment: I haven't. I am just attributing this to age. If it works, it works, and i'll just keep using it until i find something major with it, which i doubt will be the case, since i'm changing oil regularly and servicing it regularly.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Thank you so much for your help. The roughness has smoothened itself out over regular servicing of the bike. Regular oil changes seems to have done the trick, and the roughness is much reduced.